# .NET Feature Management IFeatureDefinitionProvider SQL provider

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Has anyone found or created a good SQL provider that implements `IFeatureDefinitionProvider` for the .NET Feature Management?

I've seen some stuff about implementing your own, but I was hoping that by now there would be one available. So far I have been unable to find one.